# Can't start meteor app on Vagrant (Homestead)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, vagrant

Got this terminal error after running meteor command in meteor project directory:
Unexpected mongo exit code 45. Restarting.

Vagrantfile:

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path("~/.homestead")

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/scripts/homestead.rb')

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
    end
end
```

Comment: what have you done so far to diagnose this issue? Have you at least looked up the error code and what it means?

Answer (score 1):

Trying running

`export LC_ALL=C`

On your vagrant instance this is known to solve the problem ur running in.. but I don't know if that is in your case to.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing some more detail, this may be a stab in the dark. If you show us the vagrant file you are using to create the instance, that will help.

However, this often happens when things were installed on the vagrant image using root rather than the specific user.

Comment: None of actions was made by root user